Getting a blank webview using InAppWebView, the webpage is visible when the app is sent to background and back again
I am currently using a webview Widget in Flutter using InAppWebView and its inside a BottomSheet...

Clicking a button opens a BottomSheet
BottomSheet contains a Webview which opens a URL which at first opens blank.
By pressing the home button app is sent to the background.
when the app is opened again the BottomSheet is in opened state and the webpage is visible.

Video Demo
// Inside Stateful Class
InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
InAppWebViewSettings settings = InAppWebViewSettings(
  isInspectable: kDebugMode,
  mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
  allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
  iframeAllow: "camera; microphone",
  iframeAllowFullscreen: true);

// Inside Build function
body: InAppWebView(
    key: webViewKey,
    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
      url: WebUri(widget.url),
    ),
    initialSettings: settings,
    pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
      webViewController = controller;
    },
  ),

When the link Transaction Charges is clicked a webview opens the webpage ...


Were you able to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue on Android.

Sorry haven't still been able to resolve it....

it's seems like giving url to webview is not updating after opening bottomsheet.
when you are coming from recent apps then app's UI is updating and webview gets it's url value so please check that url is static or dynamic.
if your url is dynamic than call setState method or use any state management library to refresh the Ui.
or it's a static url then, can you show me your webview code? so that i can help you out of this issue.

Edited the question with a code sample...
